# how to use require() in web application which is running inside node js

Tags: node.js

I have web application which is following below structure.

app_name

- bin
- node_modules
- public

  - images
  - javascripts
  - stylesheets
- views

  - index.html
- app.js
- package.json

i'm unable to use require() inside /public/javascripts/xxx.js file,it says **Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined**

i'm i missing something ? plz advice.

Comment: Node's `require` is only available when you run the script at the server (e.g. via `node your-script.js`). In the browser you need to use a module loader like [requirejs](http://requirejs.org), [browserify](http://browserify.org/) or [systemjs](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs).

Answer (score 0):

`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` means that you are trying use `require` in the browser (client side javascript). You cannot require CommonJS modules (i.e. those used in node.js) in the browser.

There are several ways to get around this, including RequireJS and Browserify.

I would suggest using [Browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify). You can get a good overview of the pros of using Browserify [here](http://esa-matti.suuronen.org/blog/2013/03/22/journey-from-requirejs-to-browserify/)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, my goal is to require('redis') cache server to communicate with my web application, browserify don't have predefined module like --redis-- , how can we do that?

Comment: Can anyone plz suggest?

Comment: i'm accessing Redis server by http server request.
thank you all for your advices!